# IntelliJ: Doesn't Save my edit configuration settings

Tags: intellij-idea

When i do Edit->Run Debug Configurations, the settings that i have put in for working directory, vm options etc do not stick. I would run a program and come back to see that the options are no longer set for the next run.

Is there a way to sticky these settings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can **save** your run configuration to ensure that it (and anything configured within in) is available for future use.

Click on the file/save icon in the `Run/Debug Configurations` window.

Here's a screenshot:

[image]

More details in the [docs](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-saving-temporary-run-debug-configurations.html). Specifically:

> **Saving a temporary run/debug configuration**
>
> To save a temporary configuration, do one of the following
>
> In the Run/Debug Configuration selector, choose Save .
>
> In the Run/Debug Configuration dialog box
>
> On the context menu of the editor or Project view, choose Save .

Comment: Thank you sir, much appreciated. :)

Comment: Why aren't run configurations saved automatically? Looks like a major design flaw to me.

Comment: They have been for me on Mac since forever. On Linux I do not even see an option to save which is super weird. Everything is always harder with Linux. Don't @ me. I wish it wasn't true.

Answer (score 3):

I faced the same issue that I was unable to save Run/Debug configs and funny enough the Save button is never visible even if I create a new config. So I just started creating folders for my configs which definitely save them for future use.